# how to improve the code with the constructor maybe?

Tags: javascript, constructor, conditional-statements, setinterval, clearinterval

Is my code wrong or is there a more effective way to do what i posted? I don't know how to do it better.
In the code there is a timer that restarts every time when it reaches 0.

A dynamic reading on the div.counter with the condition 'if the counter reaches 0s it must also press the button autonomously.

```
  <body>
    <h1>Callback</h1>
    <div id="timer"></div>
    <button id="btn">Button</button>
    <div id="text"></div>
  </body>

let timer = document.querySelector("#timer");
let text = document.getElementById('text')
let btn = document.getElementById('btn')

var counter = 3;

function myFn() {
  counter--
  if (counter === -1) {
    counter = 3
  }

  timer.innerText = counter
}

var myTimer = setInterval(myFn, 1000);

setInterval(() => {
  time = timer.textContent
  console.log(time)
  if (time === '0') {
    btn.click()
  }
}, 1000);

btn.onclick = function () {
  text.innerHTML += 'clicked' + '<br>'
}
```

Comment: Does your code have an issue, or are you only looking for ways to improve it? If it's latter, check out https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is the code supposed to do? Have you tested whether it works?

Comment: I want to improve it, because it is not so precise. because of the setinterval, and I think the button is also not so well placed